# How to access a lists text value from inside a loop using range in Python

Tags: python, loops

I have a loop with range but I need to access the text value from inside the loop. I can use a loop without range but I also need the range value.

```
list = ["red", "yellow". "green"]

for i in range (0, len(list)): # 3 (0-2)
    print(i) # 1, 2, 3

for i in list
    print(i) # red, yellow, green
```

How could I do something like the below

```
for i in range (0, len(list)):
    print(i) # 1, 2, 3
    print(i.text/value???) # red, yellow, green
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html?#lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `enumerate` would be a better idea for this.

```py
lst = ["red", "yellow". "green"]
for index, value in enumerate(lst):
    print(index) # 1, 2, 3
    print(value) # red, yellow, green
```

Comment: thank you! I will try this. it looks like the better way

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `i` as an index of `list`. Like this:

```
lst = ["red", "yellow", "green"]
for i in range (0, len(lst)):
    print(i) # 1, 2, 3
    print(lst[i]) # red, yellow, green
```

Notice that I renamed `list` to `lst`. This is because `list` is a reserved keyword in Python and you cannot use it as a variable name. If you try to do so, then you will run into problems.